# Besteht ein Zusammenhang zwischen "Habilitation" und "Rehabilitation"?

Tags: etymology

Ist es Zufall, dass [Rehabilitation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rehabilitation) (Wiederherstellung der Ehre, Genesung) und die [Habilitation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation) (Erlangen eines akademischen Grades) sich nur um eine Vorsilbe unterscheiden? Hängen die beiden Begriffe vielleicht irgendwie zusammen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beide Begriffe tragen im Wortstamm das lateinische *habilitare*, was auf Deutsch

> geschickt machen, geeignet machen, befähigen

bedeutet. Die Vorsilbe *re-* entspricht dem deutschen *wieder-*.

Insofern besteht zwischen den beiden Wörtern ein Zusammenhang, dass sie vom selben lateinischen Ursprungsverb abgeleitet sind.

Answer (score 2):

Beide Wörter haben ihren Ursprung aus dem Mittellateinischen *[habilitare](http://www.frag-caesar.de/lateinwoerterbuch/habilitare-uebersetzung-1.html)*:

> *habilitare*: ermöglichen, geschickt machen
>   *rehabilitare*: die Unversehrtheit wiederherstellen, jemand wieder zum Amt tauglich machen